# Sum of multiple neighboring result pairs

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have following:

```
<?php 

$numbers = count($array1);
if($numbers == 1) {
        $sum = (count($array1) == 1) ? $array1[1] - $array1[0] : 0;
        $sum2 = (count($array2) == 1) ? $array2[1] - $array2[0] : 0;
        $sum3 = (count($array3) == 1) ? $array3[1] - $array3[0] : 0;
        $sum4 = (count($array4) == 1) ? $array4[1] - $array4[0] : 0;
    } else {
        $count = count($array1);
            for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; ++$i){
                    $ez = $array1[$i];
                    $sum = $array1[$i + 1] - $ez;
            }
        $count2 = count($array2);
            for ($k = 0; $k < $count2 - 1 ; ++$k) {
                $ez1 = $array2[$k];
                $sum2 = $array2[$k + 1] - $ez1;
            }
        $count3 = count($array3);
            for ($o = 0; $o < $count3 - 1; ++$o) {
                $ez2 = $array3[$o];
                $sum3 = $array3[$o + 1] - $ez2;
            }
        $count4 = count($array4);
            for ($p = 0; $p < $count4 - 1; ++$p) {
                $ez3 = $array4[$p];
                $sum4 = $array4[$p + 1] - $ez3;
            }
}
$final_result = $sum + $sum2 + $sum3 + $sum4;
?>
```

This code is inside while loop which works with database selected results. 
I had a problem with the first result so I tried to check it manually with `if($numbers == 1)`.

Now my **first** result is fine, but `for` loop take all results from the array and starting from 0 again, which means it needs to "skip" the first result and calculate `2nd - 1st` one.

**Problem (same results):**

[image]

Is it possible do it on any other way and where am I wrong?

Comment: in all of 4 array how many possible maximum elements?

Comment: @KaushikAndani depends on selected date from-to.

Comment: why you use ++$i instead of $i++?

Comment: @KaushikAndani its same..

Comment: you starting loop with 0 that's why it take from 0, try to  start loop with 1

Comment: @KaushikAndani But how can I skip it? I set for test starting `$i = 5, $o = 5, $k = 5, $p = 5`.. And results are https://imgur.com/a/6bzp5Cp

Comment: Are you sure of what your code really do.I don't see the usefulness of the for loops in your code as you change the value of $sum. for each iteration...

Comment: @Elementary yeah, as I told, this code is inside while loop which means for every database result, $sum will change..

Comment: yep for every database result i understand but actually as you may see ,your code is written in a way you don't need at all the for loops on the four arrays as you only seems to want the difference between the two last values in each array.